# Tomcat server within eclipse not working for Gradle build project

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, gradle

I have a test project build using Gradle. I am trying to create a web application that will say Hello gradle (I am new to gradle or any build tool for that matter, so I wanted to test before getting into my project). Here is my directory structure:

```
|
| build\
| build.gradle
| gradle\
| gradlew
| gradlew.bat
| README.md
| WebContent
   | index.html
```

This is generated after running `gradle wrapper`, `gradle eclipseWtp` and `gradle build`. ( In no particular order). The build script I used is:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'

repositories {
        mavenCentral()
}

// See http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/war_plugin.html
//   Section 26.5. Convention properties
project.webAppDirName = 'WebContent'

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir 'src'
        }
        resources {
            srcDir 'src'
        }

    }
}

task wrapper (type: Wrapper){
  gradleVersion = '2.11'
}
```

I am able to successfully import this project to eclipse. I use eclipse for all the development and hence want the option of running the project from the tomcat within eclipse. It works fine for a Dynamic Web Project created using eclipse, but isn't working for my gradle build project.

The server is not starting with the following error

```
Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.server:GradleTest' did not find a matching property.

SEVERE: Error starting static Resources
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Document base /path/to/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/GradleTest does not exist or is not a readable directory
    at org.apache.naming.resources.FileDirContext.setDocBase(FileDirContext.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:5132)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5319)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1574)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1564)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/GradleTest]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1122)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:819)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1574)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1564)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/GradleTest]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Error in resourceStart()
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5320)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 more
```

I did some reading and found that adding `eclipse-wtp` solved the problem for [this](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/running-gradle-project-with-tomcat-in-eclipse/6088/3) guy. But that doesn't solve my problem. What addition configurations do I need to get tomcat running from eclipse?

Also the gradle built project doesn't have `Deployment Descriptor, JAX-WS Web Services, Javascript Resources` that normally appears in a Dynamic Web Project in eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configuring Source as `/WebContent` and Deploy Path `/` in Deployment Assembly in project properties started the tomcat server for me.